# Symfony2: Duplicate definition of column 'id' on entity in a field or discriminator column mapping

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm having trouble using entity inheritance in Symfony2. Here are my two classes:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @Orm\MappedSuperclass
 */
class Object
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
}


/**
  * @Orm\MappedSuperclass
 */
class Book extends Object
{
}
```

When I run **php app/console doctrine:schema:create** I get the following error:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]  
Duplicate definition of column 'id' on entity 'Name\SiteBundle\Entity\Book' in a field or discriminator column mapping.
```

What may be causing this?

Thanks :)

## Update:

You are right I missed this. Now I'm using single table inheritance with both classes being entities:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"object" = "Object", "book" = "Book"})
 */
```

But I still get the same error message.

Comment: Are you trying multiple inheritance? If not, I invite you to read the [documentation about MappedSuperClass](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) especially the yellow box. "MappedSuperclass cannot be an entity"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually I found yml files in Resources/config/doctrine/, which were defining my entities, instead of just using annotations.

I removed these files and it's working now.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Your answer helped me too! :)
Symfony 3.1 FOSUser Bundle.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this in a different context - in my case, I had set up an entity for single-table inheritence using `@ORM\DiscriminatorColumn`, but had included the column in my class definition as well:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\DirectoryObjectRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="kind", type="string")
 */
class DirectoryObject {
    // ...
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $kind;
}
```

Removing the `@ORM\Column` definition of `kind` fixed this issue, as Doctrine defines it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue even after adding definitions to yml file. I was trying to add weight & max weight to a class and was getting:

`Duplicate definition of column 'weight_value' on entity 'Model\ClientSuppliedProduct' in a field or discriminator column mapping.`

Then I realized it requires `columnPrefix` to be different for similar types of fields and adding following in yml solved it for me:

```
`maxWeight:`
  `class: Model\Weight`
  `columnPrefix: max_weight_`
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and error message but for me it was the other way around as @user2090861 said.

I had to remove the (unused)

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

from my entity files, cause my real mapping comes from the orm.xml files.

I hope I can help with my answer many other people, cause this exception drove me crazy the last two days!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's impossible to remove extra config files, because theay are located in third party bundle and `auto_mapping` is enabled.

In this case you should disable undesirable mappings in `app/config.yml`

```
doctrine:
orm:
    entity_managers:
        default:
            mappings:
                SonataMediaBundle: { mapping: false }
```

Answer (score 0):

Any entity must contain at least one field.

You must add at least one field in Book Entity

**Example**

```
/**
 * @Orm\MappedSuperclass
*/
class Book extends Object
{
 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
  private $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message but I had made a different mistake:

Class B had an ID and extended Class A which also had an ID (protected, not private). So I had to remove the ID from Class B.

Answer (score 0):

Or it could be that simple:

```
* @ORM\Column(name="problematic_name",...
```

problematic_name has been used twice on different attributes, because of well, copy&paste.